# Viewing an FTP server log in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have a standard filezilla FTP server running on my server and I'm wondering if I can get the log that displays in the interface to appear in a PHP web script (hosted on the same server) so I can monitor the FTP activity remotely.

Is this possible to do? Thanks! :)

Edit: I am aware that I can install the filezilla interface and log into the server interface remotely, however, my main client is a mac and there doesn't seem to be any program that can preform this task

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just write a script to do this.

A simple way is to just:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('/path/to/ftp/log');
```

P/S: You can use filezilla on mac as well.

Comment: How can I monitor the server from filezilla on mac? There is only a client version as far as I am aware.